# VNC remote keyboard

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm connecting to my Mac using another Mac and VNC. Remote Mac use VNC built-in server and local Mac use VNC Viewer for Google Chrome. The problem is that, also if keyboard layout is Italian, the keyboard layout is different from "Italian layout" on remote keyboard. Any idea why and how to solve?

Comment: Best guess is the remote machine doesn't know your local keyboard is Italian & will be using whatever the remote machine has set up.

Comment: Does this also happen when you use 'Connect to Server' by opening Finder on your local Mac, clicking Go to > Connect to Server and using this connection syntax? `vnc://hostname:port/`

Comment: The layout, in keyboard setting is correct. When I type `-` (minus) the char that is sent is `'`(single quote)

Comment: Even if is Italian Layout (the same of remote machine), the layout transmitted has less key than they are...