# VNC access using builtin macOS 'Screen Sharing' function - Keyboard issues

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

I configured the builtin macOS Screen Sharing and I can remote connect using realVNC viewer.
However the keyboard layout is wrong (despite being the same on both remote computer and the one using the VNC client).

This problem is causing me to being stuck when the computer is locked.
How can I override those keyboard settings on the server side?

### Tried fixes:

- Changing the `locale` options in the advanced settings on the client side didn't help.
- Changing the client's keyboard layout to english, or using the onscreen keyboard didn't help either.
- Using the [Apple Remote Desktop CLI](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201710) to change the settings on the server, but I couldn't find how to change the keyboard layout.

### Workaround:

I installed realVNC server on the machines and used the free "Home License" (up to 5 machines) and out of the box is was able to remote access the machines and the keyboard mapping is correct.
So I guess the issue is linked to **Apple Remote Desktop**.
But I would prefer to avoid using realVNC server and just use the builtin macOS Screen Sharing function.

### Similar issues :

- [vnc-remote-keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287820/vnc-remote-keyboard)
- [cannot-sign-in-to-mac-with-vnc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371129/cannot-sign-in-to-mac-with-vnc)